# AutoHotKey, I am trying to send parameter from Function to another script

Tags: function, parameters, autohotkey

I am trying to send parameter from Function to another script

I have two script files.

---

kss.ahk

```
Msgbox %1%
```

---

1. tried first

---

b.ahk

```
My_Fun(work)
My_Fun(arg)
{
    Run %A_ScriptDir%\kss.ahk %arg%
    return 
}
```

---

2. tried second

---

```
My_Fun(work)
My_Fun(arg)
{
    Run %A_ScriptDir%\ksson.ahk %arg%
    return 
}
```

---

I can't receive "work"  from Msgbox

How can I do?

Answer (score 1):

You're not passing in a string to your function `My_Fun()`, you're trying to pass in a variable by the name of `work`.
Such a variable doesn't exist, so you're passing in nothing.
To pass in a string, you'd do `My_Fun("work")`.

Also, `%1%`, `%2%`, `%3%`,.. is legacy.
Use `A_Args`<sup>[(docs)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm#Args)</sup> instead:
`MsgBox, % A_Args[1]`